# SQL: Outputting Multiple Rows When Joining From Same Table

Tags: sql, join, union

My question is this: Is it possible to output multiple rows when joining from the same table?
With this code for example, I would like it to output 2 rows, one for each table. Instead, what it does is gives me 1 row with all of the data.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 
    ON t2.id = t1.oldId
WHERE t1.id = '1'
```

**UPDATE**
Well the problem that I have with the UNION/UNION ALL is this: I don't know what the t1.oldId value is equal to. All I know is the id for t1. I am trying to avoid using 2 queries so is there a way I could do something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.id = '1'

UNION

SELECT t2.*
FROM table t2
WHERE t2.id = t1.oldId
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
messages_users
id    message_id   user_id   box   thread_id   latest_id
--------------------------------------------------------
8     1            1         1     NULL        NULL
9     2            1         2     NULL        16
10    2            65        1     NULL        15
11    3            65        2     2           NULL
12    3            1         1     2           NULL
13    4            1         2     2           NULL
14    4            65        1     2           NULL
15    5            65        2     2           NULL
16    6            1         1     2           NULL

Query:
SELECT mu.id FROM messages_users mu
JOIN messages_users mu2 ON mu2.latest_id IS NOT NULL
WHERE mu.user_id = '1' AND mu2.user_id = '1' AND ((mu.box = '1' 
AND mu.thread_id IS NULL AND mu.latest_id IS NULL) OR mu.id = mu2.latest_id)
```

This query fixes my problem. But it seems the answer to my question is to not use a `JOIN` but a `UNION`.

Comment: can you post some sample data? it might be easier if we can see data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean one row for t1 and one row from t2?

You're looking for UNION, not JOIN.

```
select * from table where id = 1
union
select * from table where oldid = 1
```

Comment: The ansswer to the question is explicitly a UNION ALL, not a UNION.  The UNION removes duplicates, so only one row would be returned.

Comment: That assumes that every column in t1 and t2 match exactly - which I would assume is not the case...

Comment: Read the question.  It is the same table with two different aliases.

Comment: and the join is on ID = oldID. which would indicate that the t1 record would have a different "oldID" value than the t2 record

Comment: The engine might still try to find and eliminate duplicates, as implied by `UNION`, which would likely be a performance hit. If you know for sure that there can't be duplicates, it's better just to use `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to multiply rows in a table, you need UNION ALL (not UNION):

```
select *
from ((select * from t) union all
      (select * from t)
     ) t
```

I also sometimes use a cross join to do this:

```
select *
from t cross join
     (select 1 as seqnum union all select 2) vals
```

The cross join is explicitly multiplying the number of rows, in this case, with a sequencenumber attached.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since it's the same table, you could do:

```
SELECT t2.*  
FROM table t1 
JOIN table t2  
  ON t2.id = t1.oldId 
  OR t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id = '1'
```